# cascade on foreign key in many to one associtaion

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have two classes having parent and child relationship

```
<class name="parent">   
   <id name="id">    
      <generator class="assgned"/>   
   </id>   
   <property name="currency"/>
   <property name="description" length="400"> 
</class> 

<class name="child"> 
  <id name="id">    
<generator class="native"/>   
</id>
   <property name="someprop1"/>
   <property name="someprop2">
   <many-to-one class="Parent" column="parent_field" name="parent" cascade="save-    
    update" />
</class>
```

when I insert a new row in child, it updates the existing row in child class instead of inserting a new row and mapping the new id with foreign key.

I think I am mistaken in choice of generator class and cascade option. Please help.

Comment: Where is your Java code, assuming this is a Java problem? How is this a SQL problem?

Comment: Are you setting ID of the new row first? This can cause hibernate not to know its an insert!

Comment: Please post the relevant java code where you are creating and saving entities.

Answer (score 0):

The mapping for cascade should be in Parent class with the direction to the child class..
While saving your parent if you add a new child object in the list of child along with older ones.. it will be saved in new row with auto incremented id if configured, remember if you are saving the child with parent and all child has there primary key set in the object they will update existing row in the DB as it is correct behavior of working.